# validates_one_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table that contains a column for a boolean value. I want there to be only one row that can have that boolean value be true. Does rails support such a feature?

I'm looking for something like the following:

```
Table  
id | bool_value
1  | false
2  | false
3  | true
4  | false
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this, which would only validate the uniqueness if `enabled` was set to `true` and would ignore other cases (`nil` and `false`), because `nil == false`:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :enabled, :if => :enabled
```

That should cover all cases.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

`validates_uniqueness_of :enabled, :if => :enabled`  is a pretty hack, but you have a problem with your design if *you are spreading one conceptual bit of true/falseness across multiple records.* This is going to perform/scale poorly, and can allow for inconsistency to creep in.

Lets look at some alternatives in a world where only one Answer can be Top Answer.

**Scenario 1**: Instead of an is_top_answer column on Answer, you have in some other table a field called top_answer_id, referring to an answer.

`class Site; has_one :top_answer, :class => :answer; end`

Clearly now there can be only one, and setting and getting become trivially easy, compared to the table scans your design requires.

**Scenario 2**: Answer has a foreign key to Question, and there can only be one top answer per question. You can extend the previous solution by having top_answer_id in the question table. Its common that the previous scenario will grow into this one over time.

Depending on your needs, you may also want to consider not rejecting a second boolean being true, in an after_save (part of the same transaction), simply setting all others to false. It's hardly more work than scanning the entire table to see whether it's allowed to set the current record to true.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I agree, my database design is a lot better after following your advice in Scenario 1.

Comment: Quick update - If your sites table contains the `top_answer_id`, then the relationship must be `class Site; belongs_to :top_answer, :class_name => 'Answer'; end`. `belongs_to` seems counter-intuitive at first, but it's required since the foreign key is on the Site class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
validates_each :bool_value do |record, attr, value|
  if value and Table.count(:conditions => {:bool_value => true}) > 0
    record.errors.add attr, 'There can only be one TRUE row'
  end
end
```

Refer to the ActiveRecord [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001394) for more details.